# Expo Standard build to EAS Build

Tags: react-native, expo

I was working on my own project, and was always using standard

```
expo build:ios
```

and now I had to use

```
eas build -p ios
```

flow. But It always return new errors, and seriously im so tired.

[image]

Whats wrong?
And whats the best way to build my application via EAS? Because its really messy. Working for 3 days to only publish my application. Such a terrible thing that is?